# How to ask permissions only once?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a method in the beginning of the activity to ask the permissions, but in the code when I want to get location coordinates, appear a error about permissions request.

This is for Android SDK 28.0.2. I've tried adding the permissions requeste in all lines that I request for coordinates.

*MainActivity*:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...
        checkPermissions();     
        ...
    }

public void myPosition() {

        //One of lines where appear the error
        Location loca = locaMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (loca != null) {
            mapCamera(loca.getLatitude(), loca.getLongitude());
            pass = true;
            savePosition(loca);
        }
    }

 private void checkPermissions() {

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);

        }
    }

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {

                if (!(grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                    //Show error
                    finish();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want do this permissions check only once. But now I see the following error:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: In your if statment you are using || or instead of && and. If a user has given only one of the permissions, if is not executet even if the other permisson is still needed. Maybe this causes the error.

Comment: I added the changes and I am continue seeing the error. I updated my post with a image.

Comment: Try putting the error code block inside a try catch statement

Comment: I have 5 code lines like this and I know that I can fix this errors adding the _if_ statement used in my _checkPermissions()_ method. But I want find a way to do this check only once, not add the same _if_ statements in 5 code lines. I find it redundant.

Comment: Ah ok. Seems because the function itself dont checks the permission. Execute the function only if permisson was granted, for examle in the else statement of checkPermissions and in the if statement of onRequestPermissionsResult. Need to be in a way that myPosition only can be execited if permissions was granted.

Comment: Yes, I know it but I am asking if there are another way to ask permissions only once. As I said before, I have 5 code lines in 5 different methods which need permissions and all of them show this error. I know that I can put the same code I put in _CheckPermissions()_ in all of them, but I want to write it only once in the beginning of the Activity. Is it possible?

Comment: You can put your code into a fragment. So if you activity is opening, first you ask the permission in the activity and call your fragment after the checkPermisson code. If permission get rejected you finish the activity.

Comment: I add _checkPermissions()_ method in the beginning of the activity. If user don’t apply the permissions, the error show and the activity finish, like appear on _onRequestPermissionsResult()_ method. Although I have all that code, when I want to obtain the location anywhere else I have to add the same code I already have on _checkPermissions()_. How can I check the permissions only once?